# Take advantage of database partitioning in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

If the user creates a filter that can logically be used to programmatically generate a filter that uses the partition key, **how can I make Power BI filter the query based on the partition key, not (or in addition to) the filter the user stated?**  I want this to occur both in the context of the user adding a filter to the filter pane and the context of filtering by clicking on a visualization.

Is this a problem that can be solved in DAX or M, or is it simply not possible?

Simply telling my users to use the partition key where possible in their reports is not reasonable.  I predict between 1000 and 7000 users in a variety of job descriptions ranging in tech savvy from senior application developer to jobs like warehouse worker, vehicle maintenance tech, and manager.  Trying to explain this to everyone is just not possible.

I am creating a Power BI dataset that uses a database that is on SQL Server and is partitioned.  I want Power BI to take advantage of the database partitioning when possible.  The Power BI file will be in Direct Query mode.

Testing (in SSMS) query performance and comparing taking advantage of the partitioning versus not, I measured a reduction in query run time between 50% and 97%, depending on a variety of factors (query complexity, number of tables used, etc.), if I filtered the query properly to take advantage of database partitioning.

For those who don’t know about improving query performance by taking advantage of database partitioning, given the context of this question all you need to know is this:  The fact table is partitioned based on a column that is part of the primary key.  In order for your query to take advantage of partitioning, you want to filter by the partition key in a deterministic way.

So…

Let's assume we have tables like:

**SalesFact**

| FactId | Year | SalesAmount | DateId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 100 | 12 |
| 2 | 2021 | 150 | 13 |

The SalesFact table is partitioned on Year.

**SalesDate**

| DateId | FullDate | Year | Month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2020-03-16 | 2020 | 3 | 16 |
| 13 | 2021-08-25 | 2021 | 8 | 25 |

Here is the simplest example.  If the user wants to see the sales amounts from 2020, they would drag the Year column to the filters and choose 2020 as the year.  The resulting SQL may boil down to something that looks like:

```
select fact.SalesAmount
from SalesFact fact
  inner join SalesDate dt on dt.DateId = fact.DateId
where dt.Year = 2020
```

That is a "regular speed" query because the filter does not take advantage of database partitioning.  I want the query that Power BI sends to the database server to filter on the partition key:

```
select fact.SalesAmount
from SalesFact fact
where fact.Year = 2020
```

Likewise, if the user wants to see the sales amounts on 2020-03-16, they would drag the FullDate column to the filters and choose the date.  The resulting SQL may boil down to something that looks like:

```
select fact.SalesAmount
from SalesFact fact
  inner join SalesDate dt on dt.DateId = fact.DateId
where dt.FullDate = {d '2020-03-16'}
```

I want the query that Power BI sends to the database server to also contain a filter on the partition key:

```
select fact.SalesAmount
from SalesFact fact
  inner join SalesDate dt on dt.DateId = fact.DateId
where dt.FullDate = {d '2020-03-16'}
  and fact.Year = 2020
```

This is, naturally, inconsequential for such simple queries.  But for a query involving several dimension tables from a mature data mart with tens of millions of rows per fact table, the response time for the user and the resource load on the database server can become significant.

I have been able to do this in other reporting tools that have full-featured scripting (that processes in the report prior to contacting the database server) available in the report designer.  I have been unable to locate these features in Power BI.  But I don't have 9 years of full-time experience in Power BI yet like I do in my previous reporting tool.  Any help is appreciated.